# Rails/MySQL: lazy symbol binding failed?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am a .NET developer by day and an aspiring Rails developer at night. I am trying to use Rails and MySQL as my DB. I have successfully installed both. However, I am running into a really strange problem and really need some advice on how to get these two to work together. Here is the error message I get:

> [rake --tasks] dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info
> Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
> Expected in: flat namespace
> dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info
> Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
> Expected in: flat namespace

I have scoured the StackOverflow and have tried many things. I am sincerely hoping someone can help me. I have this all installed and running on a brand new MacBook Pro Retina. I am not terribly familiar with the underlying nuts and bolts of the OS in terms of the command line but can work my way around somewhat.

How do I get rid of this problem?

#### EDITED TO SHOW GEMFILE

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'

gem 'json'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: What are you doing that is causing this error i.e. when does it happen?

Comment: I am trying to simply run the app

Comment: How? By running `rails server` and then hitting `http://localhost:3000/` in your browser?

Comment: I apologize... I am creating the app using rails new NewSite then after the bundle install I get that message. I am using RubyMine IDE and that error is being found in /usr/bin/rake

Comment: So you get the message after the initial `bundle install` that `rails new` runs itself, or are you running it yourself? What does your Gemfile look like?

Comment: @Matt you should avoid using the software that comes prepackaged with OSX. Research **[Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/)** for software (like MySQL) and something like **[rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)** for managing rubies with something like **[rbenv-gemsets](https://github.com/jamis/rbenv-gemset)** to manage gem bundles. This stuff is documented well, covered like crazy here on SO and external blogs and will give you a **much** more up-to-date, reliable system to work from.